# Check if a JavaScript function is a method for a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, instanceof, typeof

How do you detect if a function is a method for a jQuery element?

For example, `$.fn.fadeIn` is a function:

`typeof $.fn.fadeIn === 'function'  //true`

However, I need a way to distinguish it from a regular non-jQuery method.  The goal is to be able to pass a function as a parameter and then call the function correctly.

Below is an example using a function called `doIt` that takes a jQuery element and a function to be applied to the element.

Example HTML:

```
<h1>jQuery Function Test</h1>
<p class=t1>Highlight this line.</p>
<p class=t2>Hide this line.</p>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
function doIt(elem, func) {
   if (func === 'a jQuery function')  //possible?
      func.apply(elem);
   else
      func(elem);
   }

function highlight(elem) {
   elem.css('background-color', 'gold');
   }

doIt($('p.t1'), highlight);
doIt($('p.t2'), $.fn.fadeOut);
```

Line #2 of the JavaScript needs help.

Interactive version:

http://jsfiddle.net/sxduwke9/

Comment: One way would be to iterate over all properties of the jQuery objects passed in and test whether `elem[prop] === func`. Not very efficient though.

Comment: How about passing a string `"fadeOut"` instead of `$.fn.fadeOut`. Then it's a simply matter of doing: `if (typeof func === "string") elem[func](); else func(elem);`

Comment: @cookiemonster, That's a great alternative, but in my actual code I already accept strings and convert them to functions.  I suppose I could try: `(typeof func === "string" && elem[func])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution that combines the string parameter idea, checking if the method exists on the object, and support for parameters...

```
function doIt(elem, func, params) {
    if (typeof func === 'function')
        func.apply(elem, [elem].concat(params));
    else if (elem[func] && params instanceof Array)
        elem[func](params[0], params[1], params[2]);
    else if (elem[func])
        elem[func](params);
}
```

or on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxduwke9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

No. But you can remove the if statement entirely:

```
function doIt(elem, func) {
    func.apply(elem);
}

function highlight() {
    this.css('background-color', 'gold');
}

doIt($('p.t1'), highlight);
doIt($('p.t2'), $.fn.fadeOut);
```

If you want to pass more arguments around, here's a quick example:

```
function doIt(elem, func) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    func.apply(elem, args);
}

function highlight(color) {
    this.css('background-color', color);
}

doIt($('p.t1'), highlight, 'gold');
doIt($('p.t2'), $.fn.fadeOut);
```

Comment: Maybe this is the best possible solution.  In my case, however, the callback functions are actually written by users of the library, so I'll probably just need to add an option to explicitly declare if the function is a jQuery method.